# Javascript return just primary domain name

Tags: javascript

Is there a lazy way to get a variable for "top level" host without resorting to if()?

- example.com: return example.com,
- cabbages.example.com: return example.com,
- carrots.example.com: return example.com,
- otherexample.com: return otherexample.com,
- cabbages.otherexample.com: return otherexample.com,
- carots.otherexample.com: return otherexample.com,

Comment: You could try [regular expressions](http://eloquentjavascript.net/09_regexp.html) or [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: What about `cabbages.example.co.uk`? Doing this right requires knowing the naming conventions for each top-level domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the test cases that you provided, one way is to use use split, splice, and join.

```
window.location.hostname.split(".").splice(-2,2).join(".")
```

Plenty of ways to write a regular expression, but one is

```
window.location.hostname.match(/[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$/)
```

Comment: That's great, thank you very much. Went with split splice and join

Comment: what about www.google.com.au, it should be google.com.au, instead of com.au

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to get the part of the string that you want:

```
url = url.replace(/^.*?([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$/, '$1');
```

Demo:

```js
var urls = [
  'example.com',
  'cabbages.example.com',
  'carrots.example.com',
  'otherexample.com',
  'cabbages.otherexample.com',
  'carots.otherexample.com'
];

for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
  var url = urls[i].replace(/^.*?([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$/, '$1');
  console.log(url);
}
```